# How to list all the elements found in a long listing format?

Tags: shell

I use often `ls -l` to list files in a long listing format, and `find -name ...` to find elements...

Does anyone know how to list the return of `find -name ...` in a long listing format?

Thank you!

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - just use the `-ls` option:

```
$ find . -name ... -ls
```

See: [man find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Comment: Or, to get the output lined up nicely, `find ... | xargs ls -l`